# Removing the values of leafs in Data::TreeDumper

Tags: perl

I'm trying to learn how to work with the `Data::TreeDumper` module. I have a hash that looks as follows:

```
my $h = {'file1' => 1,
         'file2' => { 
                      'file3' => 3,
                      'file4' => 4
                    },
         'file5' => 5
};
```

I use `Data::TreeDumper` as following:

```
print DumpTree($h,'Contents of $h');
```

And the output is:

```
Contents of $d
|- file1 = 1
|- file2
|  |- file3 = 3
|  `- file4 = 4
`- file5 = 5
```

It works great but I would like to somehow remove the values of the **leafs** of the hash, meaning the output should be:

```
Contents of $d
|- file1 
|- file2
|  |- file3
|  `- file4
`- file5
```

After reading the docs [(link)](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::TreeDumper) I found out that I can pass a filter that will do changes on the output. But they didn't show how to do it. Also, I think that it is possible to achieve by using the `Tree::Simple` module but I prefer not to do it. If there does not exist a variable which I can set in order to get the wanted output, then can I do it with some special filter? if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters can change the labels, but you want to change the values.

So, I made a deep copy of the hash and replaced the non-ref values by empty hashes (empty arrays would work, too) and set NO_NO_ELEMENTS to get no output for them. I also had to turn off addresses (maybe you set the corresponding flag somewhere else?)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::TreeDumper;
use Storable qw{ dclone };

sub remove_leaves {
    my $h = $_[0];
    for (values %$h) {
        if (ref) {
            remove_leaves($_);
        } else {
            $_ = {};
        }
    }
}

my $h = {file1 => 1,
         file2 => {file3 => 3,
                   file4 => 4},
         file5 => 5};

my $clone = dclone($h);

remove_leaves($clone);
print DumpTree($clone, 'Contents of $h',
               NO_NO_ELEMENTS  => 1,
               DISPLAY_ADDRESS => 0);
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you! Is there a variable for `NO_NO_ELEMENTS` like the one for `DISPLAY_ADDRESS` (`$Data::TreeDumper::Displayaddress`)?

Comment: Also, is it possible to not print the title? something like: `DumpTree($clone, 'Contents of $h',
               NO_NO_ELEMENTS  => 1,
               DISPLAY_ADDRESS => 0);` Although it won't work because it will think that `NO_NO_ELEMENTS` is a title.

Comment: What do you mean by "title"?

Comment: I don't see any variable mentioned in the documentation. I haven't checked the source, though.

Comment: I check the source and sadly there is no such variable. By title I meant removing `'Contents of $h',`

Comment: You can supply `""`, but it will still print an empty line.